# Cross Compiling to Raspberry Pi from Windows with External Libraries

Tags: raspbian, cross-compilation, windows, opencv

Following this guide, http://www.a2p.it/wordpress/tech-stuff/development/remote-debugging-raspberrypi/ , I was able to cross compile from Windows to Raspberry Pi. But is it possible to cross compile with external libraries such as PCL and OpenCV. Can I just build a project using Cmake tool using the cross toolchain?

Comment: You have to cross-compile the libraries first.

Comment: Does sudo apt-get install <library-package> downloads and install prebuilt binaries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If whatever you are compiling links to, e.g., `libfoobar`, then libfoobar has to be:

- In the library path when you compile.  The easiest way to do that is to set up a basic hierarchy (`bin`, `lib`, `include`) and install them to there.  I'll refer to this as the "staging" directory.
- Versions compiled *for the pi*.  These could even be versions *from the pi*, although working out the linkage here can be much more trouble than it is worth, and you may easily end up banging your head against a wall.  The ideal thing to do is get the library sources, cross-compile them, and install into the staging directory.

WRT the staging directory, you can use the cross-compiler's sysroot directory (which contains all the basic libs, e.g., glibc), however, it is probably a better idea to make one specifically for that purpose and add `-L/wherever/` to `LDFLAGS`.  I have not used the x-tool from your link, but I presume it uses *crosstool-ng*.  If you look in the crosstool-ng docs at `5 - Using the toolchain.txt` there are extensive notes about this.  That pre-built x-tool may already have something configured along these lines.

If your library requirements are fairly straightforward, building them from source is not much of a hassle.  However, one thing you could try is to mount the pi's root directory as an NFS share (or Samba?  I don't know much about windows) and use that as a staging directory.  Then you just need to install the '-dev' packages with `apt-get`.

Comment: Regarding the latter part of your answer, I just want to confirm my understanding.  Do you mean that I would be linking my project to the root of the pi (where the installed <lib packages>) are installed and I can now cross compile?

Comment: Yeah.  So then you would compile something like `-L/mnt/lib -L/mnt/usr/lib -I/mnt/include -I/mnt/usr/include`.